# Location App on Android

Tags: android, gps, location

I have problem with stable reading on the start from this application.
In first minute or so reading get very jumpy. Between 10-100 meters’ difference even in distance.
I heard it is common error in location applications especially one using GPS.
Can I prevent this somehow with pause on reading on this start? With some fancy text like “Calculating your location” or something like that for first 10-20 seconds?
And if yes. Where I should implement this pause? So it will get readings and stabilized them but don’t mess up calculations? 
Or there is any other way to prevent messy starting reading?
Ofc any other suggestion on upgrade of current also very welcome:)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String addressString = "No address found";
    String latLongString = "Your Current Position is: ";

    double latitude = 10;
    double longitude = 10;
    double sLatitude;
    double sLongitude;
    double eLatitude;
    double eLongitude;
    double distance = 10;
    double el1 = 0;
    double el2 = 0;
    double counter = 2;

    TextView myLocationText;
    TextView myLatitude;
    TextView myLongitude;
    TextView myAddress;
    TextView startingLatitude;
    TextView startingLongitude;
    TextView endingLatitude;
    TextView endingLongitude;
    TextView myDistance;
    TextView myLogOut;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager locationManager;
        String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(context);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        myLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Latitude);
        myLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Longitude);
        myLocationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
        myAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Address);
        startingLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startingLatitude);
        startingLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startingLongitude);
        endingLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endingLatitude);
        endingLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endingLongitude);
        myDistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
        myLogOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logOut);

        if (location != null) {
            sLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            sLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        }

        updateWithNewLocation(location);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 2,
                locationListener);

    }

    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            updateWithNewLocation(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            updateWithNewLocation(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

    private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {

        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();

            eLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            eLongitude = location.getLongitude();
            distance = distance(sLatitude, eLatitude, sLongitude, eLongitude,
                    el1, el2);

            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {

                List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude,
                        longitude, 1);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    Address address = addresses.get(0);

                    for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                        sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                }
                addressString = sb.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        } else {
            latLongString = "No location found";
        }

        myLocationText.setText(latLongString);
        myLatitude.setText("Latitude: " + latitude);
        myLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + longitude);
        myAddress.setText(addressString);
        startingLatitude.setText("Starting latitude: " + sLatitude);
        startingLongitude.setText("Starting longitude: " + sLongitude);
        endingLatitude.setText("Last latitude: " + eLatitude);
        endingLongitude.setText("Last longitude: " + eLongitude);
        myDistance.setText("Your distance to starting point: " + distance);

    }

    public static double distance(double lat1, double lat2, double lon1,
            double lon2, double el1, double el2) {

        final int R = 6371; // Radius of the earth

        double latDistance = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double lonDistance = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        double a = Math.sin(latDistance / 2) * Math.sin(latDistance / 2)
                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2)
                * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        double distance = R * c * 1000; // convert to meters

        double height = el1 - el2;

        distance = Math.pow(distance, 2) + Math.pow(height, 2);
        return Math.sqrt(distance);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah , you can use the GoogleApiClient to get user location and it will take care of everything for you , it's better practise in android to use GoogleApiClient for location because it uses last known location as it's starting point and it share the location data that it collect between all the app on the device

here is some basic code logic to get you started

```
public class MainActiviy extend Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

         @Override
            protected void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }

          @Override
            protected void onStop() {
                if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
        }

        @Override
            public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);//REQUEST_LOCATION_INTERVAL 
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {



                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                            this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setMessage(R.string.permission_prompt_location);
                        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                                       MainActivity.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                        REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            }
                        });
                        builder.create().show();
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                                this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                REQUEST_LOCATION);
                    }



                    return;
                }
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

            }

     @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
                int requestCode,
                String[] permissions,
                int[] grantResults) {
          if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
              mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
          }

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();


                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        }




 @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
updateWithNewLocation( location);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks I was thinking to use it also Unfortunate we must use geofence for this project somehow criteria method use only GPS what it get messy And it had internet permission n manifest

Comment: I don't understand what geofance has to do with you not able to use googleApiClient , if anything it will be easier to implement

Comment: You think it will resolve jumping problem? It will still GPS Also somehow even with access for network I don't get access to networks location service in buildings with Wi-Fi when I'm logged in ofc.

Comment: I thought when I set criteria it should had automatically access to every resources on my phone that's including google locations

Comment: It's the best way to get location and it had build in geofancing which you can synce with API uppon internet connection

Comment: Well there is a reason google decide to rebuild the location in the googleApi

Comment: I have permissions for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in Manifest. do i need to implement this in code?

Comment: I don't understand the question, you need the manifest permissions, you'll also need the googleApi in your build.gradle

Comment: I have those permissions implemented in Manifest file. They should be active then on start right or I missing something?

Comment: Well they should but you need to grant the permission if not either in the app settings or programmatically like the code in my answer

Comment: Thank you again for help